# MySQL get ordered list of contacts by last message sent/received

Tags: php, mysql, join

this is my situation,I have 2 tables, one about friends, another about messages.
Friends table is like this:

```
user_id|friend_id|accepted
  12   |   1      |   1
  13   |   1      |   1
   1   |   3      |   1
```

accepted can be 0 or 1. (1 accepted, 0 nope)

Messages table

```
message|time    |user_id|receiver_id
  hi!  | 1328688|   1   |   12
  hey  | 1343409|   12  |   1
```

Time is a timestamp, **so i need to list in order by** **the highest timestamp for each friend**.

I need to list all contacts (that are accepted = 1) in order of last message (send/received).
In other words,  i need to group by sender and receiver, and take only one value (the last) from each friend.
The user "12" can be in user_id or friend_id, and in user_id and receiver_id...so i need to check both.

Someone can help me? Thanks guyz!

**EDIT**
my query:

```
SELECT * FROM friends,messages
                         WHERE  (friends.user_id='$my_id'
                         OR  friends.friend_id ='$my_id'
                         AND friends.accepted='1')
                         AND messages.user_id='$my_id'
                         OR messages.receiver_id='$my_id'

                         GROUP BY  friends.friend_id
                         ORDER BY messages.time DESC");
```

I tried an INNER JOIN, but it's crazy guyz (i'm not so able with mysql)

**EDIT 2**

Message Table
[image: Messages table]

Friend Table
[image: Friends table]

**EDIT 3** $my_id is variable for take my user_id

Comment: can you show the queries that you have tried so far?

Comment: What do  you really mean by `so i need to list the highest number before the others about the chat`?

Comment: example data is a bit short.  one record per table doesnt give us a great feeling about your data and no idea how your data looks like.

Comment: Edited! 
ok @RaymondNijland if you want i can add data to the table. 
The logic of the query is like facebook messanger.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What should the desired result look like?

Comment: thanks @Strawberry, the result is like Whatsapp or Facebook Messanger, so the last friend with i've chatted go on the top of the list, the others following him by the time (most recent on top, less recent on bottom)

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly. Note that your existing data set may not be properly representative.

Comment: Added screenshot! Tell me if need more information :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved**, this query worked for me

```
SELECT messages.* FROM messages, (SELECT MAX(id) as lastid
                   FROM messages
                   WHERE (messages.receiver_id = '$myid' OR messages.sender_id = '$myid')

                   GROUP BY CONCAT(LEAST(messages.receiver_id,messages.sender_id),'.',
                   GREATEST(messages.receiver_id, messages.sender_id))) as conversations
                   WHERE id = conversations.lastid
                   ORDER BY messages.time DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is more or less what you mean - hastily cobbled together.

**db schema to build example:**

```
create table if not exists `friends` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned not null,
  `friend_id` int(10) unsigned not null,
  `accepted` tinyint(3) unsigned not null default '0',
  primary key (`id`),
  key `user_id` (`user_id`),
  key `friend_id` (`friend_id`)
) engine=innodb auto_increment=3 default charset=utf8;

insert into `friends` (`id`, `user_id`, `friend_id`, `accepted`) values
    (1, 1, 2, 1),
    (2, 1, 3, 0);

create table if not exists `messages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `message` varchar(50) not null default '0',
  `time` timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
  `sender_id` int(11) not null,
  `recipient_id` int(11) not null,
  primary key (`id`),
  key `sender_id` (`sender_id`),
  key `recipient_id` (`recipient_id`)
) engine=innodb auto_increment=3 default charset=utf8;

insert into `messages` (`id`, `message`, `time`, `sender_id`, `recipient_id`) values
    (1, 'hi fuddwhack', '2018-02-20 11:32:41', 1, 2),
    (2, 'hello yersel tattyheid', '2018-02-20 11:32:57', 2, 1),
    (3, 'yellow banana', '2018-02-20 11:45:32', 3, 1),
    (4, 'green apple', '2018-02-20 11:45:43', 1, 3),
    (5, 'orange shoes', '2018-02-20 10:46:12', 2, 1),
    (6, 'red pineapple', '2018-02-20 11:46:27', 2, 3);

create table if not exists `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(50) not null default '0',
  primary key (`uid`)
) engine=innodb auto_increment=4 default charset=utf8;

insert into `users` (`uid`, `name`) values
    (1, 'daphne'),
    (2, 'velma'),
    (3, 'wilma');
```

**Basic queries to show table and data**

```
mysql> describe friends;
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id   | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| friend_id | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| accepted  | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe messages;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| message      | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| time         | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| sender_id    | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| recipient_id | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

mysql> describe users;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> select * from messages;
+----+------------------------+---------------------+-----------+--------------+
| id | message                | time                | sender_id | recipient_id |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | Hi Fuddwhack           | 2018-02-20 11:32:41 |         1 |            2 |
|  2 | hello yersel tattyheid | 2018-02-20 11:32:57 |         2 |            1 |
|  3 | Yellow banana          | 2018-02-20 11:45:32 |         3 |            1 |
|  4 | green apple            | 2018-02-20 11:45:43 |         1 |            3 |
|  5 | orange shoes           | 2018-02-20 10:46:12 |         2 |            1 |
|  6 | red pineapple          | 2018-02-20 11:46:27 |         2 |            3 |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+-----------+--------------+

mysql> select * from friends;
+----+---------+-----------+----------+
| id | user_id | friend_id | accepted |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+
|  1 |       1 |         2 |        1 |
|  2 |       1 |         3 |        0 |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+
```

**Query to find messages from user to recipient and vice-versa**

```
select * from messages m
  where 
    m.sender_id=( select f.user_id from friends f where f.friend_id=m.recipient_id and f.accepted=1 )
    or
    m.recipient_id=( select f.user_id from friends f where f.friend_id=m.sender_id and f.accepted=1 )
    order by m.time;


+----+------------------------+---------------------+-----------+--------------+
| id | message                | time                | sender_id | recipient_id |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+-----------+--------------+
|  5 | orange shoes           | 2018-02-20 10:46:12 |         2 |            1 |
|  1 | Hi Fuddwhack           | 2018-02-20 11:32:41 |         1 |            2 |
|  2 | hello yersel tattyheid | 2018-02-20 11:32:57 |         2 |            1 |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! 
But i have a problem, i need to group by sender and recipient, so i need only one value (the last) from each friend

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
select f.user_id from friends f 
left outer join messages m on (f.user_id = m.user_id)
left outer join messages m2 on (f.user_id = m.receiver_id)
where f.accepted = 1
group by f.user_id
order by m.time desc, m2.time desc
```

Comment: Thanks Artur, but i need to group by sender and recipient, so i need only one value (the last) for each friend. 
I think this query group only by user_id, it's right?